# Is possible to call an overridden method from another plugin? [Is for a Minecraft plugin]

Tags: java, sockets, plugins, minecraft

I'm coding two plugins for a program, one of this plugin is a "library plugin" and contains a lot of classes used by the other plugins, the other is one of the plugin based on this library. All works well except one thing. In my library plugin I wrote a socket class sintetized to this:

```
public class MServerSocket {
    public void initServer(int port) {
        //Code to receive message from client
        execute(input, clientOutput);
    }

    public void execute(String input, DataOutputStream clientOutput) {
        System.out.println(input);
        send(clientOutput, input);
    }

    public void send(DataOutputStream clientOutput, String output) {
        //Code to send message to client
    }
}
```

In the other plugin I extend this class and override the execute method to do something, like this:

```
public class MySocketServer extends MServerSocket {
    @Override
    public void execute(String input, DataOutputStream clientOutput) {
        //Do something
        MServerSocket.send(clientOutput, input)
    }
}
```

Now my second plugin should override my library plugin class but it doesn't. In the second plugin I call it in the main like this:

```
public class Main {
    public void onEnable() { //method called to load plugin
        private static MServerSocket socket = new MServerSocket();
        socket.initServer(12980);
    }
}
```

When I send a socket message to my socket it is printed to the console as said in the library execute method.

So here I am, can someone give me an answer and possibly a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this isn´t even close to beeing compilable, having a `private static` variable within a `member` method

Comment: `MySocketServer` will override code from `MServerSocket`. Problem is: you never call any code from `MySocketServer`.

Comment: No it's not private, to simplify i copied some parts of the code and this "private static MServerSocket socket = new MServerSocket(); " was not in the function

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in the code you posted:

```
  MServerSocket.send(clientOutput, input);
```

That is incorrect because`send` is not a `static` method.  It should be written as this:

```
 this.send(clientOutput, input);
```

or

```
 super.send(clientOutput, input);
```

or simply

```
 send(clientOutput, input);
```

---

But to answer your question, the reason that you are seeing the "print" is that you are calling the initServer method on an instance that is a `MServerSocket` instance rather than a `MyServerSocket` instance.  Since it is an `MServerSocket` instance, *it doesn't have the override method*.